# Split sentence into words according to it language correctly with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Background: I am coding a word-wrapping function for any string in HTML canvas. I hope to create a function that works for all languages.

For English, maybe `.split(" ")` is enough, but this does not work for other language. For example, mixed language:

```
今天很美,Peter和Jane去了St. Thomas  // (Today is beautiful, Peter and Jane go to St. Thomas 123)
```

If uses `split("")`, then:

```
["今", "天", "很", "美", ",", "P", "e", "t", "e", ... "�", "�", "�"]
```

Note: the non-BMP characters, i.e.  will split into "�", "�", "�"

I want some approach that can split the words correctly, as such:

```
["今", "天", "很", "美", ",", "Peter", "和", "Jane", ... "St.", " ", "Thomas", " ", ""]
```

Any idea? Use regex in `.split(/ ??? /)`? But how to write the regex "properly" *(able to handle multiple languages)*?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/split-word